# Set the Cache-Control max-age of ArcGIS Server 10.1 tiles to a custom value

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, cache

Using ArcGIS Server 10.1 I have a cached service. The service is set to allow clients to cache tiles and the images do contain max-age values:

```
Cache-Control   private, max-age=86400
```

However, I would like to change this value.

I could find the `cacheControlMaxAge` property in the [ESRI documentation for 10.3.1](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/map-cache-usage-by-clients.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_42689C8B0E044765BE9EBBAB6A58456E), but this property does not exist in my 10.1 service. These are the available properties:

```
"properties": {
  "virtualCacheDir": "/rest/directories/arcgiscache",
  "maxImageHeight": "2048",
  "textAntialiasingMode": "Force",
  "maxImageWidth": "2048",
  "enableDynamicLayers": "false",
  "dynamicDataWorkspaces": "",
  "supportedImageReturnTypes": "URL",
  "disableIdentifyRelates": "false",
  "isCached": "true",
  "maxScale": "250",
  "maxBufferCount": "100",
  "maxRecordCount": "1000",
  "schemaLockingEnabled": "true",
  "filePath": "\\\\dir\\a.msd",
  "cacheOnDemand": "false",
  "useLocalCacheDir": "true",
  "virtualOutputDir": "/rest/directories/arcgisoutput",
  "outputDir": "\\\\dir\\arcgisserver\\directories\\arcgisoutput",
  "cacheExtent": "full",
  "minScale": "200000",
  "maxDomainCodeCount": "25000",
  "tilingScheme": "2",
  "ignoreCache": "false",
  "antialiasingMode": "None",
  "clientCachingAllowed": "true",
  "cacheDir": "\\\\dir\\arcgisserver\\directories\\arcgiscache"
 }
```

How can I set the max-age to be a custom value?

Comment: I think this is a new feature at 10.3, in which case it isn't possible at 10.1.